# How can I add Amount using Cyber source SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cybersource

I downloaded Cyber Source SDK iOS from Github. It is also working fine. But I need to set total amount and I can not find any parameter in SDK. How to set amount in Cyber source using SDK?

I don't know it is set by SDK or Backend(API). Please check my code below:

```
//Card data
        let cardData = InAppSDKCardData.init()
        cardData.accountNumber = txtCardNumber.text
        cardData.expirationMonth = txtMonth.text
        cardData.expirationYear = txtYear.text
        cardData.cvNumber = txtCVV.text

        //Create Transaction object
        let transactionObj = InAppSDKTransactionObject.init()
        transactionObj.billTo = getBillToData()
        transactionObj.cardData = cardData

        //Get the Merchant data and credentials and assign.
        transactionObj.merchant = getMerchantData()

        //Set the End point / Environment. Test or Live
        InAppSDKSettings.sharedInstance()?.inAppSDKEnvironment = INAPPSDK_ENV_TEST

        //Enable log for debugging
        InAppSDKSettings.sharedInstance()?.enableLog = true

        //Obtain the gateway sharted instance.
        let gatWay = InAppSDKGateway.sharedInstance()

        result = (gatWay?.performPaymentDataEncryption(transactionObj, with: self))!

        if (result) {
            NSLog("InAppSDK: Request Accepted. Expect the response in the delegate method.");
        }
        else {
            NSLog("InAppSDK: Request NOT Accepted. Verify the input values if any one is invalid.");
        }
```

And I got a response like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-1623853623"><wsu:Created>2019-08-01T10:25:43.747Z</wsu:Created></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></soap:Header><soap:Body><c:replyMessage xmlns:c="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.120"><c:merchantReferenceCode>Cyber_iOS</c:merchantReferenceCode><c:requestID>5646551432976553503004</c:requestID><c:decision>ACCEPT</c:decision><c:reasonCode>100</c:reasonCode><c:requestToken>AhizbwSTMhmkg5ScYGkcEQFRp++q/94CP9hk0ky9GK+AnABMoAny</c:requestToken><c:encryptedPayment><c:data>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</c:data></c:encryptedPayment><c:encryptPaymentDataReply><c:reasonCode>100</c:reasonCode><c:requestDateTime>2019-08-01T10:25:43Z</c:requestDateTime></c:encryptPaymentDataReply><c:reserved><ics_message xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data:ics"><encrypt_payment_data_rcode>1</encrypt_payment_data_rcode><ics_return_code>1000000</ics_return_code><encrypt_payment_data_rmsg>Request was processed successfully.</encrypt_payment_data_rmsg><ics_rcode>1</ics_rcode><encrypt_payment_data_return_code>1001000</encrypt_payment_data_return_code><ics_rmsg>Request was processed successfully.</ics_rmsg><request_id>5646551432976553503004</request_id><encrypt_payment_data.reason_code>100</encrypt_payment_data.reason_code><encrypt_payment_data_rflag>SOK</encrypt_payment_data_rflag><request_token>AhizbwSTMhmkg5ScYGkcEQFRp++q/94CP9hk0ky9GK+AnABMoAny</request_token><ics_decision_reason_code>100</ics_decision_reason_code><encrypt_payment_data_request_date_time>2019-08-01T102543Z</encrypt_payment_data_request_date_time><ics_rflag>SOK</ics_rflag><merchant_ref_number>Cyber_iOS</merchant_ref_number><encrypted_payment_data>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</encrypted_payment_data></ics_message></c:reserved></c:replyMessage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This SDK is intended for one purpose - to reduce PCI scope by encrypting the card data which can then be passed to your server. Since it is only encrypting the card data there is no need for an amount.

Once you have the encrypted data you pass that to your server and can then use it to authorize the card. See "Using the Payment Blob" on this page https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-ios-sdk. This is the point where you will need the amount. You will also have to pass the amount to your server if it is coming from your iOS App.